# Old data sorting perfect but if i add new then Descending not correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have some data in Core data. After running one method in background, I am getting new data from API and I want to sort that data by date and time. I have stored date and time both in string. See my code below,

```
abc2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

managedObjectContext=[self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Message"];
//self.device = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
abc2=[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSArray *sortedEventArray2;
[abc2 sortUsingComparator:^(id dict1, id dict2) {

    NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dict1 valueForKey:@"date"],[dict1 valueForKey:@"time"]]];
    NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dict2 valueForKey:@"date"],[dict1 valueForKey:@"time"]]];

    return [date2 compare:date1];
}];

sortedEventArray2=abc2;
```

[image: click here]

Check 11:00 AM msg is 2nd and 10:56 AM is 1st. Means if I send message now it goes below also static data filter correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
[dict2 valueForKey:@"date"],[dict1 valueForKey:@"time"]]];

 --------------------------------^
```

Shouldn't be this `dict2`?